# Return List Values

Tags: c#, list, linq

how to return list values without using `foreach` or `for`?

For example i have these variables :

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("First");
mylist.Add("Second");
mylist.Add("Third");
string finalstring = "";
```

Instead of using this code :

```
foreach(string str in mylist)
{
    finalstring = str + " - ";
}
```

I want to use something like this :

```
finalstring = mylist.something.somthing...;
```

And get an output like this :

```
"First - Second - Third"
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you done any reasearch on your own before? If you did, it's hard to believe you missed `String.Join`.

Comment: @Sefe , I haven't done researches much, i make my own methods most the times

Comment: @Ali - I recommend always research, especially before asking for help from others - it's the difference between learning and becoming better to not..

Answer (score 0):

Just use `string.Join`;

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("First");
mylist.Add("Second");
mylist.Add("Third");
string finalstring = string.Join("-",mylist);
```